# EF Core 3.0 MoveNext Error when Include using SingleOrDefault

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.0

I read different solution and tried different implementations without any result.
Using different implementation the error is always the same : "System.InvalidOperationException: Enumerator failed to MoveNextAsync."

This is where the exception is generated.

```
var portfolioTrades = await _context
      .Portfolios
      .Include(PortfolioEntityTypeConfiguration.TradesList)
      .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.id == id);
```

The include is handled in way

```
  builder.OwnsMany<Trade>(TradesList, x =>
            {
                x.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("portfolio_id");
                x.ToTable("product_trade", SchemaNames.Public);

                x.Property<TradeID>("id");
                x.Property<DateTimeOffset>("_date").HasColumnName("date");
                x.Property("_details").HasColumnName("details");
                x.Property<Guid>("_schemaId").HasColumnName("schema_id");

                x.HasKey(x => x.id);

            });
```

EF execute this query and return 1 record

```
SELECT t.id, t.description, t.end_client_name, t.name, t0.id, t0.details, t0.portfolio_id
FROM (
    SELECT p.id, p.description, p.end_client_name, p.name
    FROM account.portfolio AS p
    WHERE p.id = '3adcaff1-de64-4ae3-b8b7-c390d76aa0bd'
    LIMIT 2
) AS t
LEFT JOIN product_trade AS t0 ON t.id = t0.portfolio_id
ORDER BY t.id, t0.id
```

Here below Entities

```
 public class Trade : Entity
{
    public TradeID id { get; private set; }

    private DateTimeOffset _date { get; set; }

    public JObject _details { get; set; }

    private Guid _schemaId { get; set; }

    private Trade()
    {
        id = new TradeID(Guid.NewGuid());
    }

    private Trade( DateTimeOffset date, string details, Guid schema_id)
    {
        id = new TradeID(Guid.NewGuid());
        _date = date;
        _schemaId = schema_id;
        _details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(details);
    }

    internal static Trade Create(DateTimeOffset date, string details, Guid schema_id)
    {
        return new Trade(date, details, schema_id);
    }

}
```

}

```
public class Portfolio : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public PortfolioID id { get; private set; }

    private string _name { get; set; }

    private string _end_client_name { get; set; }

    private string _description { get; set; }

    private readonly List<Trade> _trades;

    private Portfolio()
    {
       _trades = new List<Trade>();
    }
}
```

// error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Enumerator failed to MoveNextAsync.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Rx.Products.Infrastructure.Domain.Portfolios.PortfolioRepository.GetByPortfolioIdAsync(PortfolioID id) in ....\PortfolioRepository.cs:line 37
   at Rx.Products.Application.Portfolios.CreateTrade.CreateTradeCommandHandler.Handle(CreateTradeCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in ...\CreateTradeCommandHandler.cs:line 19
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at Rx.Products.API.TradesController.RegisterCustomer(CreateTradeRequest new_trade) in ....\TradesController.cs:line 65
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 726
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:54315
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.24.1
Postman-Token: 2aabfa69-9d5c-4637-9d48-02a713077235
```

The [ms guide about relation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) generate the same error.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is there any more info in the exception? Can you add stacktrace please?

Comment: @GuruStron , is sure, I added it. tnx

Comment: @GuruStron just to provide  you more details. if I remove the Include the code works properly and the entity is filled.

Comment: It seems for some reason EF getting multiple records. Try `FirstOrDefaultAsync` and `SingleOrDefault`. See [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18742) and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19639) issues.

Comment: @GuruStron with SingleOrDefault query change, modifying LIMIT to 1 but the error  returned is the same.  Thanks for the links was some of the article I read without any result :/

Answer (score 0):

1. I think it would really help you to have a public `Portfolio.Trades` property that can be used for navigation and to define the relationship between the `Portfolio` class and the `Trade` class.

```cs
    public class Portfolio : Entity, IAggregateRoot
    {
        // Other class members defined above...

        // New public navigation property for the relationship.
        public IReadOnlyList<Trade> Trades => _trades.AsReadOnly();
    }
```

2. If you use a `OwnsMany` relationship, then you don't need to use the `.Include` statement in the query.  If you use a `HasMany` relationship, then you will need to use the `.Include` statement.

Using `HasMany` and `Include`:

```cs
builder.HasMany(port.Trades, x =>
            {
                // Other configuration code defined above...
            });

var portfolioTrades = await _context
      .Portfolios
      .Include(port => port.Trades)
      .SingleOrDefaultAsync(port => port.id == id);
```

Using `OwnsMany` and not `Include`:

```cs
builder.OwnsMany(port.Trades, x =>
            {
                // Other configuration code defined above...
            });

var portfolioTrades = await _context
      .Portfolios
      .SingleOrDefaultAsync(port => port.id == id);
```

Using a `OwnsMany` relationship will mean that all of the child `Trade` objects will automatically be queried for you.  Using a `HasMany` relationship allows you to specify including the child `Trade` objects as part of your query.

Comment: Tnx Steve for support. Modifying the entity Portfolio has y suggest I've got a new error. ---> The type 'Trade' cannot be marked as owned because a non-owned entity type with the same name already exists.

Comment: obviously I removed the "include" using OwnsMany

Comment: If there is another entity other than `Portfolio` that has a relationship to the `Trade` entity, then the `Trade` entity cannot be owned by the `Portfolio` entity.  The easiest way to resolve that error would be to use a `HasMany` relationship and use the `.Include` statement in the query.

I like using `OwnsMany` relationships where there is a relatively "small" number of child items and the collection of child items doesn't grow without bounds.  You can read more about the differences here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516830/ef-core-hasmany-vs-ownsmany

Comment: builder.OwnsMany<ProductIdentifier>(ProductIdentifiers, i =>{ ..... }); I used the code you suggested to me but the error is still the same. The entity is called using           var product = await _context
                .Products
                      .Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleAsync();                                                         and the error is always the same Enumerator failed to MoveNextAsync. thanks Massimo

Comment: .Products.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToListAsync(); using this statement the query generated if executed inside a sql tool run correctly but vs freezed ...

Comment: SELECT.....  p0.product_id, p0.identifier_id
FROM public.product AS p
LEFT JOIN public.product_identifier AS p0 ON p.id = p0.product_id
WHERE p.id = $1