# ASP.NET Core 3.1. problem with updating collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I migrating application in ASP.NET Core from 2.1 to 3.1 and have problems with Entity Framework.

I have an entity with `GlassesLenses` collection:

```
public class GlassesContract : BaseUpdateEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    private readonly List<GlassesLenses> _glassesLenses = new List<GlassesLenses>();
    public ICollection<GlassesLenses> GlassesLenses => _glassesLenses.AsReadOnly().ToList();

    public void ClearLenses()
    {
        _glassesLenses.RemoveRange(0, _glassesLenses.Count);
    }

    public void AddLens(GlassesLenses lens)
    {
        _glassesLenses.Add(lens);
    }
}
```

And a service for updating lenses:

```
public async Task<GlassesContract> ChangeSetting(GlassesContract contract)
{
    // clean lenses
    contract.ClearLenses();
    await _glassesContractRepository.UpdateAsync(contract);

    // add new lens
    contract.AddLens(new GlassesLenses());

    await _glassesContractRepository.UpdateAsync(contract);
    return contract;
}
```

In version 2.1 the behaviour is working fine. The collection was cleared (EF marks entity for delete) and after add new lens EF mark as new entity for insert.

In version 3.1, instead of delete and insert, EF Core only does an update.

```
// delete lens
UPDATE public."GlassesContracts" 
SET "AccountId" = @p0, "BalancePaymentDeposit" = @p1, ...
WHERE "Id" = @p42 AND "SysRowVer" IS NULL
RETURNING "SysRowVer";

// add new lens
UPDATE public."GlassesContracts" 
SET "AccountId" = @p0, "BalancePaymentDeposit" = @p1, ...
WHERE "Id" = @p42 AND "SysRowVer" IS NULL
RETURNING "SysRowVer";

UPDATE public."GlassesLenses" 
SET "Availability" = @p43, "Color" = @p44, ...
WHERE "Id" = @p77 AND "SysRowVer" IS NULL
RETURNING "SysRowVer";
```

Mapping DbContext:

```
// mapping relationship
    modelBuilder.Entity<GlassesContract>()
      .HasMany(_ => _.GlassesLenses)
      .WithOne(_ => _.GlassesContract)
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<GlassesLenses>()
      .HasOne(_ => _.GlassesContract)
      .WithMany(_ => _.GlassesLenses);

// mapping Value objects
modelBuilder.Entity<GlassesLenses>().OwnsOne(o => o.Price).WithOwner();
modelBuilder.Entity<GlassesLenses>().OwnsOne(o => o.PriceExclVat).WithOwner();
modelBuilder.Entity<GlassesLenses>().OwnsOne(o => o.FinalPrice).WithOwner();
modelBuilder.Entity<GlassesLenses>().OwnsOne(o => o.FinalPriceExclVat).WithOwner();
modelBuilder.Entity<GlassesLenses>().OwnsOne(o => o.Discount).WithOwner();
```

If I mark entity with `AddAsync(entity)` or `Remove(entity)` this will generate right SQL as INSERT and DELETE.

Can you anyone explain why the new version 3.1 is not as smart as v2.1 and why `SysRowVer` (concurrency token) is always NULL and not updated?

Thank you so much

**UPDATE**

The entity tracker says 'entity GlassesLens is modified' after AddLens(..) call. I don't understand why if is added as new.

**---SOLVED---**

Comment: I can't find contract.AddLens(new GlassesLenses()); Can you show it?

Comment: Thanks. And pls add UpdateAsync metod since it all about update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution (my knowledge mistake). Problem is breaking-changes in EF Core 3+.

We are using GUID as primary key. This is not generated value, because our application using DDD rules and entity framework changed this behaviour.

You need tell EF your ID is not generated by add `DatabaseGenerated` attribute

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public Guid Id { get; private set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
```

or fluent in DbContext

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<GlassesLenses>()
    .Property(e => e.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedNever();
```

God bless [this post](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18044)

And original is

[DetectChanges honors store-generated key values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#detectchanges-honors-store-generated-key-values)

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

In the EF database context table mapping use

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GlassesContract >(m =>
{
        m.OwnsMany(i => i.GlassesLenses); //instead of HasMany().WithOne()
});
```

For more explanation on OwnsMany, check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58516869/4381062)

Comment: thank you but this is not my case because GlassesLenses are different table entity not a value objects :(